# Best route to fit a UITextField to UITableView cell

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, uitextfield

I am wondering what is the best way to make a UITextField fit a UITableView cell.

I have used this method before:

```
@implementation UITextField (custom)
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 0, bounds.origin.y + 10,
                      bounds.size.width - 30, bounds.size.height - 16);
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
@end
```

But this causes an issue:

```
Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class
```

Although I have seen ways to hide these warnings, it feels like this is more of a hack than a correct method.

What is the best way to fit a UItextField to a cell. This is my field:

```
// Username field
usernameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 43))];
usernameField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

It is input into the cell like this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:usernameField];
    }
```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing this by overriding your custom UITableViewCell's layoutSubviews method.  Much simpler there imo.  Something like:

```
    - (void)layoutSubviews
    {
        [super layoutSubviews];
        float  w, h;

        w = (int)(self.frame.size.width - 30);          
            h = (int)(self.frame.size.height - 16);

        [self.detailTextLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, w, h)];
    }
```

Here's a fragment of the custom cell initialization

```
    @interface MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    }
    @end

    @implementation MyCustomCell


    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
            }
            return self;
    }
```

Here's a fragment of where the custom cell would be created:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain more about how please?

Comment: Just added details about the layoutSubviews method.  I'm assuming you already have a custom UITableViewCell?

Comment: Does this affect all sub views? I programatically setup all my subviews, would this affect all of them or only the text fields

Comment: just the subview in the uitableviewcell that you explicitly set.  in the example, I just set the UITableViewCell's built-in detailTextLabel frame.  The [super layoutSubviews] makes sure everything else is drawn as before

Comment: Just to confirm this is a UIViewController setup as a TableViewDelegate and all changes made programatically as opposed to Interface Builder and Nibs

Comment: So where should this code go, it wouldn't go in the controller view code

Comment: It goes in a custom UITableViewCell object

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25103/discussion-between-stuartm-and-mike-m)

Comment: I have set this up but makes no difference to my text fields within the cell. I have tried changing the floats but no difference is made, I have updated my question with an image of the issue

Comment: if add the textfield to the cell directly (instead of the contentview) you should get control over its position.  you can set a breakpoint in layoutSubviews to make sure that the textfield is not nil.

Comment: I have tried adding [cell addSubView:usernameField]; instead but makes no difference. I also updated your first part of code to be [self.contentView setFrame... instead and this partly works. It sorts the layout but also makes the clear (x) button within the field slightly out so isn't a solution this way. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I sorted the issue. I updated your initial code to self.contentView and then updated my field UITextField width and height to sort the clear box (x) issue. Thanks